# What is the differrences between Talk and Google+ Messenger?

Tags: google-talk, google-plus, chat

Both are the chatting tools of Google.

I use Talk since I use Gmail to chat with my friend and when I see Google+ Messenger, I just thought it is Talk but the two are NOT the same at all - i.e. chatting with one person on Talk  and he/she will NOT receive it Google+ Messenger.

This is so confusing. What is the differences then? Why there are two chat tools like this?

*Update*
The funny thing is that Google+ Messenger is used for chatting with Google+ users from Android phone. But when I log in my Google+ page, I can ONLY talk with Talk friends !?!? I want to continue my last chat with a friend on Google+ from my PC, but now I cannot. So funny!

[image]

Comment: Hopefully this shouldn't be a problem/confusion for too much longer, it looks like Google will soon be merging all of their instant messaging and presence apps into one, Google Babble: http://techwhack.co/google-babble-merge-google-talk-messenger-hangouts-43398/  http://www.geek.com/android/google-expected-to-unify-chat-under-the-name-babble-1543151/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Google Talk** syncs to your Gmail account. This offers free instant messaging to all your Google contacts that you have invited to “talk” with. You can use the services within the Gmail web page, or download Google Talk and install it on your computer or smart phone.

**Google+ Messenger**, originally called “Huddle”, is a sub service to Google+.

The big difference between the two is that Google+ Messenger is the instant messaging service that is synced to your Google+ account, not your Gmail account. People who are added to your “circles” are the ones that are able to be messaged with. Another difference is that Google+ Messenger allows people to have group chats.

[Source: difference-between-google-talk-google-messenger-and-google-hangouts](http://splog.samuelpaasch.com/2012/10/difference-between-google-talk-google-messenger-and-google-hangouts/)

Comment: Yeah you're right. Group chatting is what not available in Talk.

Comment: Well, I cannot find way to use this sub service "Huddle" on Goolge+ site...

Comment: No, you can't. The two services are totally incompatible with each other (not to mention the other messaging services that Google offers). There are rumors (and some evidence) about a forthcoming unifying chat service called Babel.

Comment: As @GAThrawn shared above, the "rumor" is Babble http://www.geek.com/android/google-expected-to-unify-chat-under-the-name-babble-1543151/

Comment: And on Google+ website, we chat by Talk instead of "Huddle", so funny :(

Answer (score 1):

Google have now integrated all of their chat and messaging services into one app on Android, [Google Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk) *(not Babble as was [previously rumoured](http://www.geek.com/android/google-expected-to-unify-chat-under-the-name-babble-1543151/))*.

From the app's description:

> Use Hangouts on computers, Android and Apple devices.
>
> Hangouts stay in sync across devices so
>   you can start or continue them anywhere.

In particular Google Talk, GMail Talk, Google+ Messenger and Google+ Hangouts (group video chat) are all integrated in this.

Google Voice isn't fully integrated yet (in particular [SMS integration may be "coming soon"](http://bgr.com/2013/05/16/google-hangouts-sms-integration-confirmed/)), and you can [opt out from receiving incoming calls through Hangouts](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3144495?hl=en&ref_topic=2944922) but as Voice is still only available in the US it shouldn't affect too many people.

You may need to upgrade your Gmail Chat to the new Hangouts experience by:

> Hangouts works right inside Gmail, where Chat did before. You can upgrade Chat to Hangouts by clicking on your photo icon in Gmail's chat list.

You may need to [set up your Google+ circles to allow members to message you](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111929?hl=en&ref_topic=2944922).

More info on the [main Hangouts page](http://www.google.com/hangouts/) and in the [Hangouts help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks GAThrawn. This is the right result we need in chatting by Google tool